# Make JButton Close a Window But Run Code In WindowClosing(WindowsEvent e) Before Closing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, windowlistener

I have to save the state of the program in a xml when the user clicks the Close Button or another JButton which says Exit on it. I have it so it runs using a WindowListener when the Window is closing it runs it. But that only works if you click the Red X close button, but not when you have the other button. I could run it before I do System.exit(0) in actionListener for button but some of the classes I need information from I do not have access from that place.

This is for the frame.

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener(){
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0){}
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0){}
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0)
    {
        myScreen.write.writeToXmlFile(myScreen.pics, myScreen.row, myScreen.col);
    }
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0){}
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0){}
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0){}
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0){}
});
```

This is the code in button.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.exit(0);
}
```

I do not have access to myScreen from the class that has button in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I do not have access to myScreen from the class that has button in it.
```

[JButton#doClick();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28int%29) can do that

but correct way could be too (maybe)

- `public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0)`

1st. void or class

- `create screenshot`

2.nd void or class

- `setVisible(false) for Top-Level Container(s)`

3rd void or class

- `save applications states`

4th void or class

- `System.exit()`

sure you can put all 4 voids (classes) to the one, but in a.m. case is code only more clear and readable

Comment: very smart thinking! i didn't know you can make a "virtual" click. I just made a virtual button in class with access and when this is pressed i call doClick and then do the stuff before exiting. Pure Genius!

Comment: @Captain Gh0st glad to help you